# Submit form button doesnt work after signing PDF in Python?

Tags: python, pdflib

The issue im facing is the that after you sign the pdf and lock the fields,you cant click on the submit Form button.I would like to be able to sign then submit the PDF by clicking the SubmitForm buttoN

```
        p.create_field(365, 233, 568, 208, "Signature","signature", self.options['signature_tf']);
        Name = getval("account_name")
        optlist = "url={mailto:james@gmail.com?subject=%20Internal%20Settings"+str(Name)+"&cc="  + "} exportmethod=pdf";           
        action = p.create_action("SubmitForm", optlist);
        optlist = "action={activate " + str(action) + "} linewidth=0";
        p.create_annotation(240, 190,340,160, "Link", optlist);
```

Comment: Unrelated to your immediate question, Python 2 is no longer supported, do you have a good reason to not be using Python 3 instead?

Comment: The backend of the platform is built in Python2

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?